# AVCaptureDevice isInUseByAnotherApplication always returns false

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I'm doing a basic application on Objective-C and the AVFoundation framework, I wanna detect if the built in camera for Mac is being used by another application, I have managed to do it, but it always returns false even when I'm using the camera with another software.

I have a function that wraps this code and is executed every 2 seconds:

```
NSArray *devices =  [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for(AVCaptureDevice *camera in devices){
        NSLog([camera isInUseByAnotherApplication] ? @"YES DEVICE BEING USED": @"DEVICE NOT BEING USED");
        NSLog([camera isSuspended] ? @"YES DEVICE SUSPENDED": @"DEVICE NOT suspended");
        NSLog([camera manufacturer]);
        NSLog([camera localizedName]);

    }
```

The problem is, I always get the same result:

```
2017-01-06 13:02:24.657 Befective Agent[13749:175226] DEVICE NOT BEING USED
2017-01-06 13:02:24.658 Befective Agent[13749:175226] DEVICE NOT suspended
2017-01-06 13:02:24.658 Befective Agent[13749:175226] Apple Inc.
2017-01-06 13:02:24.658 Befective Agent[13749:175226] FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
```

**EDIT**

The camera that appears on the software it's the same that this one, and I only have the built-in camera of the MacBook Pro.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

The softwares that I have used to use the camera are:

- Hangouts
- Skype
- RedBooth
- Slack

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the below link, it will return true only if some other app is exclusively using the camera:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1389512-isinusebyanotherapplication

And that exclusive lock is acquired like below:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1387810-lockforconfiguration

Clarification: key word is ***exclusive***. The camera can only be ***exclusively*** locked via `lockForConfiguration`, and that's only temporary. So, multiple apps can use the camera at the same time.

Comment: As a matter of fact, when I'm testing my code I'm using the camera with one of the softwares I mentioned on the question.

Comment: Using those software doesn't mean that they are exclusively using the camera.

For example, when you are using hangouts, you would still be able to use Skype showing that hangout or skype is not using the camera EXCLUSIVELY.

Comment: That explains a lot, so, there is another way to detect if the camera is being used?

Comment: Can you provide with the scenario why do you need it? 

Because, as all the apps are able to use the camera simultaneously, you can also access the camera and perform your operations. Or moreover, you can acquire an exclusive lock to perform your operations.

Comment: We are doing a software that detect when an application is being used and detects if the camera is being used too, the app I'm building doesn't need to se the camera, just to detect whether it's being used or not.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres did you ever find a solution for determining if it "was in use" but not necessarily exclusively?  Have the need for a project and was let down...thought I hit a home run when I seen that field "isInUseByAnotherApplication"

Comment: @afreeland I didn't, I left that company, long ago